# Is it possible to dump wastewater from shower and sinks to the soil if we only use biodegradable products (Quebec/Ontario)?

Tags: renovation, building-regulations, building, house

Is is possible to dump waste water from showers and sinks directly into the ground using pierced pipes with siphons somewhere near the property as long as we only use washing products which are biodegradable (e.g. pure Castile with peppermint and such) - in Quebec or Ontario?

Comment: Not sure about your local codes but here "graywater" systems still need permitting approval. Check with your local authorities to see if it is permissible where you are.

Comment: It would not be allowed where I live, so it depends on location. How long will the soap take to degrade

Comment: Check out reed beds natural water treatment is possible BUT choice of soap etc is crucial and you also need sufficient space.

Comment: One book is "Lifting the lid" by Halestrap and Harper.

Comment: Very dependent on local rules, possibly more local than the province, unless the province as a whole prohibits it. *Most* places with a sewer system won't permit this type of use. Some places that do permit it limit it to the kitchen sink, due to small amounts of unpleasant material potentially showing up in bathroom sinks, clothes washers, and showers. Permaculture resources have typical examples of reed bed filtration, etc. if it is allowed where you are.

Comment: I would guess that most likely _not_ because while _you_ may pinky-promise to only use natural, biodegradable products, the next resident may not and they'd end up dumping "nasty" stuff directly into the ground. As others noted, check your local regulations.

Comment: In extremely water short locales it definitely makes sense to divert all greywater to irrigation on site. But in most places with ample water for household use, it could be counter productive to divert greywater away from the sanitary sewer. The reason is that putting greywater into the sanitary sewer helps keep the sanitary sewer flushed and flowing well.